# Possible to remove geoserver raster legend watermark?

Tags: geoserver

If you get a legend from a geoserver raster with a opacity="0" watermask , you'll see a big red x... Like in this:

[image: example raster legend]

from the [geoserver GetLegendGraphic docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html).

Anyone know if it's possible to hack this out with geoserver? Current workflow is to create these legend graphics and then use an image editor to create static legends, but that's no fun to maintain.

Comment: can you add the relevant section from your SLD

Comment: Ciao,
I don't think this is configurable (and I am the one who coded that, but it was a while ago :P). 

Just out of curiosity, what would you expect there. I use that approach to show for which value we are getting something transparent (a.k.a no data).

Comment: @simogeo Sorry it took me a bit to respond: Nothing is expected there. In my mind if you are making it transparent, it means you do not want the audience to see or think about it, eg No Data or just data not relevant to the current map. Also, a red X on white background 'clashes' with a lot of site designs.

Comment: @iant This isn't as much a sld issue as geoserver function - it's any ColorMapEntry where opacity="0"